# Angular - custom directive after image src loaded

Tags: angular, angular-directive

i've got a problem.

I have to get width and height of an image after loaded with the directive [src].

I got this html that get he url from a parent object with @input:

```
<img fitImageSize [src]="content.openGraphImage.contentUrl"/>
```

and here my directive to get the dimensions:

import { Directive, ElementRef, AfterContentInit } from '@angular/core';

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[fitImageSize]'
})
export class FitImageSizeDirective implements AfterContentInit {

  el: ElementRef
  private imgWidth: any;
  private imgHeight: any;

  constructor(_el:ElementRef) {
    this.el = _el;
  }

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.imgWidth = this.el.nativeElement.offsetWidth;
    this.imgHeight = this.el.nativeElement.offsetHeight;    
    console.log(this.imgWidth);
  }
}
```

The console.log always print "0". I don't know how to launch the directive process after the image is loaded. Can someone help me please? I searched before asking but i haven't found any answers yet.

Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to Use different lifecycle hook to get the image width. Which called after the components view has been full initialized.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[fitImageSize]'
})
export class FitImageSizeDirective implements AfterViewInit {

  el: ElementRef
  private imgWidth: any;
  private imgHeight: any;

  constructor(_el:ElementRef) {
    this.el = _el;
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.imgWidth = this.el.nativeElement.offsetWidth;
    this.imgHeight = this.el.nativeElement.offsetHeight;    
    console.log(this.imgWidth);
  }
}
```

Comment: In this way not in every case i got the image dimension before the ngAfterViewInit. From a  list of 30 img elements almost the half get the size

Comment: are you looping the image list?

Comment: Correct. The parent component creates a list of components hosting my img

Comment: <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3" *ngFor="let content of contents; trackBy:index">
<app-daily-update-box [content]="content"></app-daily-update-box>
</div>

Comment: in app-daily-update-box I got the images that I need to get the size

Comment: try to console the image before if condition

Comment: then try to use setTimeout